# Why are the video and audio out-of-sync when I watch YouTube?

Tags: streaming, youtube, video-streaming

I have a 2-year old MacBook that works perfectly. I'm running Snow Leopard and I use Safari as my web browser. Whenever I watch videos on YouTube, the audio and video are out-of-sync. At the start of the video, both are in-sync, but as you get near the end, they are way out-of-sync. After an hour, the video and audio will be off by 5 or 6 or so seconds. I tried switching web browsers to Mozilla Firefox, but the same thing happens. I have TechToolPro and totally optimized the drive, and it still happens with both browsers. What is causing this ?

Comment: Do you run the latest version of Adobe Flash Player? You could also try to switch to the html 5 beta, which needs no flash anymore. Would be interesting if this makes a difference. You can switch to the html 5 version of YouTube on http://www.youtube.com/html5

Comment: Do you have pausing and skipping of the Video or Audio?  You might have a problem, but I can tell you for sure that there are many videos on youtube that are out of sync, and many that the sync migrates (gets worse over time). Do you have an example one (and specify which res and type you were playing)?